# Jquery-Ui Tab List

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Hello guys I'm using jquery-ui tabs. I want to change it's text color. I know how to do it but the real problem that I'm facing is that each list option has a anchor tab. Now due to some reason I gave that anchor tab this property `color:#7e8c99 !important;`.

If I remove this important it will disturb my UI so to change the color of the tab list text  I did some inline styling and that worked out pretty well but the problem I started facing after it was when I select a tab I want to change the color of the text but I can't do it. Can you please tell me what can I do.

and one thing more I want t vertical small line with the selected option like this [screenshot of the image](http://screencast.com/t/2F0cBHGQn3P3).How can I achieve that

Comment: You should use the theme-roller from jQueryUI website to make your own theme: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ and am I using the tab option from there.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElement');
elem.setAttribute('style','color: #fff !important')
```